# Compare SQL Result Sets While Leaving in Blanks Where No Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way of building a result set which is comprised a comparison of data from two specified years.

So it the result set would look something akin to this

```
PRODUCT - 2019 QTY - 2020 QTY

Car        10         10
Boat       10         0
Plane      0          10
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Pivot is not supported. Emulate...

Comment: @Akina darn, if that's the case then I guess I'll just have to get clever with my existing result sets

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  I am guessing something like this:

```
select product,
       sum( year = 2019 ) as qty_2019,
       sum( year = 2020 ) as qty_2020
from t
group by product;
```

This assumes that your raw data has one row per item you want to count.

If you need to sum quantity from a column then use:

```
select product,
       sum( case when year = 2019 then quantity else 0 end ) as qty_2019,
       sum( case when year = 2020 then quantity else 0 end ) as qty_2020
from t
group by product;
```

Comment: Going to have to do some manual tallying just to make sure but the second answer  seems to be it it! Thank you!